# How to make a built-in device driver in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I know how to make loadable kernel modules in Linux.
But i want that loadable kernel module to be a part of the kernel , and after booting that driver should automatically load, like most of the other general driver.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do for your query 
1) building your `module as statically compiled along with kernel`(your source code should reside in kernel tree ),so while building build it static which come as a part of kernel,
so when kernel boots your module will be loaded.
2)Same as above but `while building build as dynamic loadable module so that wheneever required you can load it`.

to illustrate above concept you can try below link for simple helloworld example.

http://www.agusbj.staff.ugm.ac.id/abjfile/Chap8.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure modprobe to load automatically driver after kernel boot. Here an [example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules) of configuration.

If you want to a built-in module, you must re-compile the kernel, and set Y in the configuration file on all modules that you want inside the kernel