# How to add my source code to Kernel source tree

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I've an I2C storage CHIP attached with system, A kernel space driver program of that CHIP is functioning with insmod / rmmod from running system.

But I would like to add this program with kernel source, so that on Kernel booting (from zImage) it will read from I2C CHIP, and Print something (e.g. Serial #) from it.

My question is, is it enough to add the driver object with `kernel/Makefile`
as `obj-y += ?`

Comment: Which kernel and which OS?

Comment: Tagged three times with "linux" and I asked which OS. tsk, tsk, tsk. But it is different for most distributions, so which distribution?

Comment: ha ha, embedded - well 4.1.15 for iMX6

Comment: I normaly just download the sources, look at the common suspects and quickly answer your question but teh source is not only hard to find, they also want me to register. Too much trouble. So look yourself: it seems as if they use systemd. If that is the case look into `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf`. Debian (and Ubuntu, too) has a shortcut file `/etc/modules` where they put the modules they need at boot time. These embedded Linuxes are mostly based on Debian, so you might give it a try before I need to register at NXP.com

Comment: @meAbab: Yes, your approach should work, but my confidence level is just below what it would take to post this as an answer.  You may wish to consult a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19542631) and its answer and links.

Comment: Also, if your driver generates any `printk()` output, you will be able to verify from `dmesg` that it was started.  And you can [pass](http://elinux.org/Initcall_Debug) `initcall_debug` as a kernel parameter if you want `dmesg` to show you each of the hundreds of modules that are started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while searching for Kernel module writing and so on, you'll find a hundreds of thousands "hello_world.c" program, that will describe how you can print
hello_world at kernel log, when your kernel and system all working and up. Which are called loadable kernel module, using program like insmod to load and rmmod to unload.

But, I was searching how to load my own script (i.e. that hello_world.c) when kernel is booting, and wanna see something on console that exactly coming from kernel at booting time, then google is almost silent.

Well, its just not difficult, and quite easy. What I've done by myself to get the printk() message at kernel booting is -

Kept the `hello_world.c` program inside `./kernel/driver` (You can keep it almost anywhere inside Kernel source folder also can make your own folder, but that will require your own Makefile).

And edit the `./kernel/driver/Makefile` to add `obj-y   += hello_world.o` 
at the end of the Makefile.

Then compile the full kernel and generated zImage transferred to sd-card. 
While booting, just after USB HID core driver, I am able to see my custom message from `hello_world printk()`.

```
[    3.652944] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.657253] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.660152] HELLO: HELLOING WORLD from KERNEL BINARY
```

NOTE:- Unlike, loadable module, function maked with __exit would never called by compile when subjected code is in-built with kernel source.

i.e. in Such case `hello_world.c` is "Programmed to received (read include) but can't never leave"